# How to delete header row in R shiny dataframe being output using renderTable?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

[image]

How to delete the header row in the table? I'm using renderTable to output the table and setting the colnames to empty strings.
colnames(df) <- c("", "")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`colnames(df) <- c("","")` does not do what you want here. You want `colnames = FALSE` in your `renderTable()` call.

[image: no header row with colnames = FALSE]

Here is a simple example. Note that the result is the same with or without the `colnames<-` line. I can reproduce your image with `colnames = TRUE`

[image: header row present with default colnames argument]

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    flowLayout(
        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("testTable")
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    dat <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3),b = c(4,5,6),c = c(7,8,9))
    colnames(dat) <- c("","","")
    output$testTable <- renderTable(dat, colnames = FALSE, bordered = TRUE)
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```